# Asynchronous ajax call for appending table row with data

Tags: jquery, ajax

// This is the jsp page code:

```
function doAjaxPost()
{
    var City=$('#City').val();
    window.alert(City,+"New City Created");
    $.ajax
    ({
    type: "GET",
    async : true,
    url: "http://localhost:8080/OnlineStore/kmsg/grocery/AddCity",
    data: "City=" +City,
    }).done(function( data, type, xml)
            {
                    console.log(data);

                     $("#Tab tbody").append(data);

            }).fail(function()
            {
                    alert("Something Bad Happened table cannot be reloaded");
            });

}; 
<body>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="doAjaxPost()"/>
<table id="Tab" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="85%">
         <thead>
            <col width="100">
            <col width="70">
            <col width="70">
            <col width="100">
            <tr bgcolor="#F0F8FF">
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>CityAdmin</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
        <tbody>
        </table>     
</body>
```

//   This is the controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/AddCity")  
public @ResponseBody List<CityModel> AddCity(@RequestParam(value = "City")    String City1) throws Exception
{ 
      return cityAdapter.insertCity(City1);
}
```

//    This is Json response Data That is verified by firebug extension:

```
 [Object { city="add",  blocked=false,  cityadmin=null,  more...}, Object { city="addme",  blocked=false,  cityadmin=null,  more...}, Object { city="addmeplease",  blocked=false,  cityadmin=null,  more...}, Object { city="fonds",  blocked=false,  cityadmin=null,  more...}, Object { city="fondsm",  blocked=false,  cityadmin=null,  more...}, Object { city="hjty",  blocked=false,  cityadmin=null,  more...}, Object { city="me",  blocked=false,  cityadmin=null,  more...}, Object { city="nb",  blocked=false,  cityadmin=null,  more...}, Object { city="q",  blocked=false,  cityadmin=null,  more...}, Object { city="quick",  blocked=false,  cityadmin=null,  more...}
```

/*  Data is coming,
    but my page is not refreshing asynchnouly . 
    Can anyone Help me, Please. */

Comment: What exactly is the error message, at what line in the code does it break?

Comment: @JuanMendes it doesn't break data is coming in response but i want the table to be refreshed without reloading the page.

Comment: i think something is wrong with your JSON, Can you please update ?

Comment: i solved the problem but now i want the previous data to be cleaned up from table and table to be updated with new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// in this way the data starts appending in table.

```
 for(var i=0;i< data.length;i++)
 {      
      var obj = data[i];
      var vcity = obj["city"];
      var vstatus = obj["status"];
      var vaction = obj["action"];
      var vcityadmin = obj["cityAdmin"];
      var update = "<tr><td>"+ vcity +"</td><td>"+vstatus+"</td><td>"+ vaction + "</td><td>"+vcityadmin+"</td></tr>";

      $("#Tab tbody").append(update);
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this is the better option, the logic should create one long list of html code to append and after the for has finished, append it all at once. As the append operation is slow and costly. Much more better results would be to just append all preprocessed html at once. See the DOM Manipulation part of this article http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery-standards/

Comment: In my case the data coming from web service is very less(1 or 2 rows) so i don't have to worry to much about slowness of append

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate a markup from the Json you have provided

Let say this is your Json response

`{ "city":"add",  "Status":"Status",  "Action" :"Action", "CityAdmin": "CityAdmin" }`

update your ajax callback function to like

```
.done(function( data, type, xml)
{
    console.log(data);
    var Markup = "<tr><td>"+ data.city +"</td><td>"+data.Status+"</td><td>"+ data.Action + "</td><td>"+data.CityAdmin+"</td></tr>";
    $("#Tab tbody").append(Markup);
})
```

**Edit**: Added a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/h26gbx3t/1/),

As json provided is not valid, i have created a sample generating table from object array.

```
$(function() {
   var json = [];
   var item = {
     'city': 'city1',
     "Status": "Status",
     "Action": "Action1",
     "CityAdmin": "CityAdmin1"
   };
   json.push(item);

   $.each(json, function(i, data) {
   console.log(i,data);
     $("#Tab").append("<tr><td>" + data.city + "</td><td>" + data.Status + "</td><td>" + data.Action + "</td><td>" + data.CityAdmin + "</td></tr>");
   });
 });
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: `table` generate without loop?? Hope this works for you??

Comment: data appended to all the columns is->  undefined

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen your console log if it is [Object] Then it is json array and you should make loop to render each object as follows:

```
.done(function( data, type, xml){
console.log(data);
var html="";
$.each(data,function(index,result){
html+ = "<tr><td>"+ result.city +"</td><td>"+result.Status+"</td><td>"+ result.Action + "</td><td>"+result.CityAdmin+"</td></tr>";
}
$("#Tab tbody").append(html);
});
```

Comment: Undefined data is loaded into the table each time i tried to enter the data !

Comment: Can you please check your console log and see what you are getting. Also please close your tbody tag however it doesn't effect anything but still.